# highlight text in html not working

Tags: html, spring-mvc, highlight, highlighting

I would like to highlight a text which is returned from server like below

```
This is my name <em>John</em>
```

I debugged in the server and the above string is returned.
But the text is not getting highlighted when it is rendered in the browser.

It shows up like below

```
"This is my name <em>John</em>"
```

The browser view source is shown below

```
This is my name &lt;em&gt;John&lt;/em&gt;
```

Should I escape the "<" and ">" symbols ? .
I am using spring mvc in this application and thymeleaf for generating html

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(results)}">
                    <h3>Search Results</h3>
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Title</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr th:each="result : ${results}">
                            <td th:text="${result.id}">Id</td>
                            <td th:text="${result.title}">Title</td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
```

Comment: You should either change your encoding on the HTML page or you should use StringEscapeUtils in Java to escape your text.

Comment: it depends on how you are displaying in browser.if you are using jquery try using $('id').html() not text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution

Title

Instead of `th.text` , use `th.utext`

Answer (score -4):

You can use **HTML5** tag also for Highlight

```
<p>test test test <mark>test</mark> today.</p>
```